# Android App getting very slow using background image

Tags: android, performance, imageview

In my application menu slider and horizontal slider code added. In Horizontal layout inside tow Linear layout each are different background.

If i will give same background working file. If i will give different background app getting very slow.

below i given my code and layout.

**My layout code :**

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/relBg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/img1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relBg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/img2" >

            <com.application.utils.HorizontalPager
                android:id="@+id/horizontal_pager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/homebg"" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                layout="@layout/homepageview" />
        </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/cal_bg" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                layout="@layout/calendarview" />
        </LinearLayout>

</com.application.utils.HorizontalPager>
      </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

image sizes are 40kb only.

In this two relative layout using different images, if i use like this app getting very slow.

**my Code:**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        scrollView = (FacebookSlideView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_scroll_with_list_menu, null);
        setContentView(scrollView);

        final Stack stack=new Stack();
        menu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_menu, null);
        app = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homepage, null);

        btnSlide = (Button) app.findViewById(R.id.BtnSlide);
        fadeGray_Rel = (LinearLayout)app.findViewById(R.id.fadeGray_Rel);   
        fadeGray_Rel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                slideAnimation(scrollView, menu);
            }
        });
```

If i use same image both Relative layout working fine, not getting slow.

my logcat details :

```
11-13 14:37:24.834: I/Choreographer(2605): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-13 14:37:24.838: D/OpenGLRenderer(2605): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 68, 11632640, 13043632
11-13 14:37:24.838: D/OpenGLRenderer(2605): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb96d2358): name, size, mSize = 75, 1048576, 14092208
11-13 14:37:24.838: D/OpenGLRenderer(2605): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 69, 11632640, 2459568
11-13 14:37:25.078: D/OpenGLRenderer(2605): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb96fdfa0): name, size, mSize = 76, 11632640, 14092208
```

thanks

Comment: what are the dimensions of your images?

Comment: Though your image is only 40kb only, when it converted to bitmap, its size get increased my friend. It is rendered to Drawable which is native decoding.

Comment: its working fine. images dimensions are too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve with this piece of code?
From the log, it looks like you app consumes a lot of resources. If the layout you provided is complete, then I think you should definitely go for some lighter options like LinearLayout.

By the way, I noticed that your two relative layouts have the same id, you might want to change that.

Comment: ask your questions in comment, pls